# angular2 2.0.0 UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12, npm WARN angular2-jwt@0.1.22 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.11

Tags: node.js, angular, angular2-jwt

this is dependencies from my package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.20",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.22",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "es6-promise": "^3.1.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
    "es7-reflect-metadata": "^1.6.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.0.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
```

I get warning of angular2-jwt dependency, but I need this pack.
And this is a warning message:

```
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12
npm WARN angular2-jwt@0.1.22 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.11
```

Any ideas?, Thanks.

Comment: Did you try depending on `rxjs@5.0.0-beta.11` instead of `rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12`?

Answer (score 0):

Such a warning can be ignored. `angular2-jwt` just needs it peer dependencies updated to match the release version of angular2. Everything will work and is installed as expected

Answer (score 0):

you need to tell at the sytemjs where is the angular2-jwt path so you need to include in the map object.
'angular2-jwt': 'npm:angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js'

Answer (score 0):

Be sure, you have in package.json strings:

```
"devDependencies": {
    ....
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ....
    "@types/systemjs": "^0.19.32",
    "angular": "^1.5.0",
    "angular-animate": "^1.5.0",
    "angular-mocks": "^1.5.0",
    "base64-js": "^1.2.0",
    "bower": "^1.3.12",
    ....
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/ng2-dropdown-treeview

or

```
+-- ng2-dropdown-treeview@0.1.4
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY zone.js@0.6.26
```

I have added the dependency in system.config.js file for `ng2-dropdown-treeview`, then it works for me.

```
'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
        'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
        'lodash': 'npm:lodash/lodash.min.js',
        'ng2-dropdown-treeview': 'npm:ng2-dropdown-treeview/bundles/ng2-dropdown-treeview.umd.js',
```